# Printing out only odd values in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I'm just starting out in Python and I can't seem to work this practice question out.

Write a function that takes in a collection and returns a list of elements of all values that are odd. You should ignore any non-numeric elements in the collection.

Required Signature: def odd_numbers1(x):

for example, calling odd_numbers1([1,2,3,3,'3']) will return [1,3,3]

for example, calling odd_numbers1([False,True,3,5.0,7.5]) will return [True,3, 5.0]

This is what I have so far but I hit an error when I reach '3'.

````
    for i in x:
        if x %2 == 0 or type(x) != int:
            None
        else:
            print(x)
    
x = [1,2,3,3,'3']

odd_numbers1([1,2,3,3,'3'])```
````

Comment: Check `type(x)` *before* checking `x%2`.  Thanks to [short-circuiting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not), if the first condition of an `or` expression returns `True`, the second condition will not be checked, so you won't try to modulo a string.

Comment: Also, instead of that `None`, you can use the `pass` keyword to denote an empty block.

Answer (score 1):

`if x %2 == 0 or type(x) != int` will be evaluated from left to right. If you have a string, '3', then it will check the modulus before checking if the type is int. You should reverse the order of checking and can also use `isinstance`: `if not isinstance(x, int) or x % 2 == 0`.

This will work because of short circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

@chrispresso is exactly right, your checking the modulus before you know if its an int so you need to reverse that logic. Personally I would change the if statement to say. If it is an int, and its not divisable by two then print. That to me looks cleaner and there is no need for an else part

```py
def odd_numbers1(x):
    for i in x:
        if isinstance(i, int) and i % 2 != 0:
            print(i)

odd_numbers1([1, 2, 3, 3, '3'])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1
3
3
```

Answer (score 0):

The question speaks of functions and returns, so just printing out the list might not be a correct answer. In addition to @Chrispresso's answer, the simplest way would be something like so:

```
def odd_numbers1(x):
    retval = []
    for i in x:
        if type(x) != int or x%2==0:
            continue
        else:
            retval.append(x)
    return retval
```

List comprehensions are a great feature of Python that could also really help you out here.